# Moving data from MySQL to mongoDB via Python - unicode string error

Tags: python, mongodb, unicode, utf-8, ascii

i am storing device tokens for Google Cloud Messaging in a mongoDB collection

the problem i am having is one of the device tokens in my dataset (being moved from MySQL) contains `\x87\` which the python mongo driver is reading as an ascii code and so giving me the error `bson.errors.InvalidStringData: strings in documents must be valid UTF-8: ...`

is there a way in python of making the driver ignore the ascii code and just read it as a string of characters without having to do something annoying like escape the back slashes?

Because the token is a valid token created by the google SDK its possible that this might happen again and i dont want to lose tokens if i can help it, i also don't want to have to run any operations on the tokens when i select them from the database as i will be pulling several million tokens at a time so this would add a lot of overhead to the token loading process.

here is an example of how i am building up the documents to add to mongo

```
for row in rows: # rows coming from an existing MySQL databse table
    rows_out.append({
        'token_id': row['token_id'],
        'token_string': row['token_string'],
        'token_added': row['token_update'],
        'token_platform': 'D',
        'token_update': 0,
        'update_count': 0,
        'user_country': 'uk'
    })
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Edit:

## load tokens from mysql and dump them in mongo

```
def create_insert(rows):
    rows_out = []
    for row in rows:
        rows_out.append({
            'token_id': row['token_id'],
            'token_string': row['token_string'],
            'token_added': row['token_update'],
            'token_platform': 'D',
            'token_update': 0,
            'update_count': 0,
            'user_country': 'uk'
        })

    return rows_out

while True:
    cur = mysql.cursor()
    assert isinstance(cur, DictCursor)

    cur.execute("""
    SELECT
      token_id,
      token_string,
      token_update
    FROM
      user_push_token
    LIMIT
      %d
    OFFSET
      %d
    """ % (SELECT_COUNT, tokens_done), None)
    rows = cur.fetchall()

    col.insert(create_insert(rows)) # pymongo collection cursor

    tokens_done += len(rows)
    if len(rows) < SELECT_COUNT:
        break
```

Comment: Can you include the code which adds this to mongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure on a complete explanation for your problem, but on a hunch, try changing this line:

```
'token_string': row['token_string'],
```

to

```
'token_string': row['token_string'].encode("UTF-8"),
```

At the very least, it will highlight better where in the process the failure is occurring.

Comment: this gives the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 137` because it reads \x87\ as the ascii code 0x87